# How can I join two tables with REALM

Tags: react-native, realm, mobile-development

I am new to REALM and I am trying to join two tables but I can't find information of sql query for realm (I am using React Native)

Tables are ChatRoom and Message. ChatRoom has multiple Messages. I would like to get all chatrooms with only one most lastest message for each chatroom.

```
ChatRoom.schema = {
    name: 'fcm_chat_room',
    primaryKey: 'chat_room_id',
    properties: {
        chat_room_id:  'string',
        chat_room_name: {type: 'string', default: ''},
        chat_room_date: 'date'
    }
};

Message.schema = {
    name: 'fcm_message',
    primaryKey: 'message_id',
    properties: {
        message_id:  'string',
        chat_room_id: 'string',
        sender_id: 'string',
        sender_reg_id: 'string',
        message: 'string',
        msg_date: 'date',
        is_read: {type: 'bool', default: false}
    }
};
```

Comment: Realm is not a relational database, it has *relationship* where you directly point to the other "table", it doesn't have join by id

Comment: What version of Realm is this again

Comment: Maybe reading https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#relationships will help.

Comment: My Realm version is v2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example, it will help you to join table in realm database.

```
    const CarSchema = {
 name: 'Car',
 properties: {
   make:  'string',
   model: 'string',
   miles: {type: 'int', default: 0},
 }
};
const PersonSchema = {
 name: 'Person',
 properties: {
   name:     'string',
   birthday: 'date',
   cars:     {type: 'list', objectType: 'Car'},
   picture:  {type: 'data', optional: true}, // optional property
 }
};
// Initialize a Realm with Car and Person models
let realm = new Realm({schema: [CarSchema, PersonSchema]});

Combine React Native

const Realm = require('realm');

class  extends Component {
render() {
  let realm = new Realm({
    schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string'}}]
  });

  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex'});
  });

  return (


        Count of Dogs in Realm: {realm.objects('Dog').length}


  );
}
}
```